# ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, ocaml

I built and install OCAML on my Mac and wanted run an ocaml binary file namely test
So I did ./test and I got:

-bash: ./test: /home/linkenhe/usr/local/godi/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

How should I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `test` is a bytecode file, not a binary file.

Where did you get the file `test`? The problem is that it's looking for the OCaml bytecode interpreter in the wrong place.

If you have installed OCaml, you should have a program named `ocamlrun`. You should check that you do. If so, you can run `test` like this:

```
# Test that ocamlrun exists
$ which ocamlrun
/usr/local/bin/ocamlrun

# Use it to run bytecode.
$ ocamlrun test
```